# How to tweak google books api to perform a search by ISBN

Tags: php, json, ajax, google-books

I'm trying to tweak a line of php code in a php file that set up to access the Google Books api (cgoogleBooksApi.class.php) to perform books seaches by ISBN_10 and ISBN_13. It accesses a volume collection. The original line of code is this:

```
'isbn'=>(isset($arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'])?$arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier']:''),
```

I've tried to change the line of code to this after checking out this webpage that gave some info on the JSON file I'm trying to parse. (https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes#method_books_volumes_get) I was trying to use the value(volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[].type) like this:

```
'isbn'=>(isset($arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers']['type']['ISBN_10'])?$arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['type']['ISBN_13']:''),
```

But it didn't work. Is there something I've missed? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

It looks like something worked after I did this:

```
'isbn'=>(isset($arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['type']['ISBN_10'])?$arrstrValue2['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['type']['ISBN_13']:''),
```

However, I could only input ISBNs without any dashes. Now I'm wondering how I can set things up so that if somebody enters an ISBN with a dash, it will work.

Comment: When I tried to input an ISBN with a dash, the api class didn't like it and would give the "No books found" error, just like I've coded it. But I tweaked the line again, so now if I add an ISBN without dashes, it seems to work.

Comment: No, a dash like "-"